# Is it possible to get shared mailbox mails using outlook mail api

Tags: outlook-restapi

I am using outlook mail api, and trying to get emails from a shared mailbox. 
Currently the mails of the user mailbox are fetched. I cant find a way to keep the same user but different mailbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't (at least not currently). When you use the Authorization Code Grant flow to log in a user, the user consents only to allow the app to access **their** information. That consent doesn't include other folks information that they've shared with that user.

If you change your application to use the Client Credentials flow, then an administrator can grant the application access to all mailboxes in their organization. That's not quite the same scenario, but if your app needs to access multiple mailboxes, it might be a better solution for you.