# What is the purpose of the new "Read user and shared mail" delegated scope in Azure AD portal for Office 365 Exchange Online

Tags: office365api, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi, azure-active-directory

What is the purpose of the new delegated scope *"Read user and shared mail"* in Azure AD for Office 365 Exchange Online.

Is it for accessing shared mailbox with Outlook REST Api? [It seemed impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780650/is-it-possible-to-get-shared-mailbox-mails-using-outlook-mail-api) until now.
Is there some documentation available? Is this scope requires *admin_consent*?

[image: Read user and shared mail in delegated scope]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This permission is used for accessing the messages from the shared mailbox. However we need to specify the shared mailbox we want to retrieve the messages from. Here is an example for your reference:

```
GET: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/sharedmailbox@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/messages
```

> > Is there some documentation available? Is this scope requires admin_consent?

I didn't find the any document about this scope and based on the test this scope doesn't require admin consent.

Comment: Thank you! The only weak point I see is that for now I cannot "discover" the shared mailboxes. Is it possible with REST apis? Maybe using EWS?

Comment: No. At present, there is no such REST API we can get the mailboxs shared with user. And I am not able to find the shared mailbox using EWS. But it can be done by using PowerShell for Exchange Online. You can use the command `Get-Mailbox|Get-MailboxPermission -user "user1"` to find the mailboxs **user1** had permissions. You may submit the feedback [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) if you require the Office 365 REST to support this feature.

Comment: Thank you! I just had a look at the PoSh solution you provide. The problem is that I would like to use it in my MutliTenant solution that uses OAUTH and OpenIDConnect and it seems that Enter-PSSesion does not support connection with Authentication Bearer (delegated authentication token)

Comment: I have added the feature request in MS Uservoice [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/15438267-support-the-discoverability-of-shared-mailboxes)